# Update multiple rows based on values in other rows in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update multiple rows based on value in other rows with matching id.

Table structure:

```
ID   |    Sub-ID | value
----------------------------
1    |      1    |    a
1    |      2    |    b
1    |      3    |    c
2    |      1    |    x
2    |      2    |    y
2    |      3    |    z
3    |      1    |    k
3    |      2    |    l
3    |      3    |    m
```

I need to update value of SubID = 2 with value of SubId=3 for  a specific IDs (where ID in other table )

The result should be (base on the above):

```
ID   |    Sub-ID | value
----------------------------
1    |      1    |    a
1    |      2    |    c
1    |      3    |    c
2    |      1    |    x
2    |      2    |    y
2    |      3    |    z
3    |      1    |    k
3    |      2    |    m
3    |      3    |    m
```

What will be the most efficient way to implement it?

This what I have right now:

```
UPDATE data_tab tab1
   SET (value) =
          (SELECT tab2.value
             FROM data_tab tab2
            WHERE tab1.id = tab2.id 
              AND tab1.sub_id = 2 AND tab2.sub_id = 3 
              )      
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1    FROM ids_table 
                WHERE id = tab1.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is something like this:

```
UPDATE data_tab tab1
   SET value = (SELECT tab2.value
                FROM data_tab tab2
                WHERE tab1.id = tab2.id AND
                      tab2.sub_id = 3
              )
   WHERE tab1.id in (select id from ids_table) and
         tab1.sub_id = 2;
```

In other words, your original query is fine.  I think it is more efficient to move the condition on `sub_id = 2` to the outer query.

Comment: _"I need to update value of SubID = 2 with value of SubId=3 for a specific IDs (where ID in other table )"_

Answer (score 1):

What you've done looks okay; whatever happens you're going to have to do those table scans. It *may* be quicker (and it looks cleaner) if you use a MERGE statement:

```
merge into data_tab o
using ( select id, value
          from data_tab a
          join ids_table b
            on a.id = b.id
         where a.subid = 3
               ) n
   on ( o.id = n.id )
 when matched then
      update
         set o.value = n.value
       where o.subid = 2
```

Comment: maybe I don't understand OP right, but why do you need the `ROWID` ? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48575/11

Comment: The rowid was a stupid mistake @A.B.Cade; it's normally more efficient in a self-join but I wasn't thinking about the WHERE clauses...